# group data by season according to the exact dates

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a csv file containing 4 years of data and i am trying to group data per season over the 4 years , differently saying, i need to summarize and plot my whole data into 4 season only .
here's a look on my data  file :

```
timestamp,heure,lat,lon,impact,type
2006-01-01 00:00:00,13:58:43,33.837,-9.205,10.3,1
2006-01-02 00:00:00,00:07:28,34.5293,-10.2384,17.7,1
2007-02-01 00:00:00,23:01:03,35.0617,-1.435,-17.1,2
2007-02-02 00:00:00,01:14:29,36.5685,0.9043,36.8,1
2008-01-01 00:00:00,05:03:51,34.1919,-12.5061,-48.9,1
2008-01-02 00:00:00,05:03:51,34.1919,-12.5061,-48.9,1
....
2011-12-31 00:00:00,05:03:51,34.1919,-12.5061,-48.9,1
```

and here's my desired output :

```
winter     (the mean value of impacts)
summer     (the mean value of impacts)
autumn      ....
spring      .....
```

Actually i've tried this code :

```
names =["timestamp","heure","lat","lon","impact","type"]
data = pd.read_csv('flash.txt',names=names, parse_dates=['timestamp'],index_col=['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)

spring = range(80, 172)
summer = range(172, 264)
fall = range(264, 355)

def season(x):
    if x in spring:
       return 'Spring'
    if x in summer:
       return 'Summer'
    if x in fall:
       return 'Fall'
   else :
       return 'Winter'

 data['SEASON'] = data.index.to_series().dt.month.map(lambda x : season(x))
 data['impact'] = data['impact'].abs()
 seasonly = data.groupby('SEASON')['impact'].mean()
```

and i got this horrible result :
 [image]

where am i mistaken ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`DatetimeIndex.dayofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofyear.html):

```
data['SEASON'] = data.index.dayofyear.map(season)
```

Another solution with [`pandas.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [0, 91, 183, 275, 366]
labels=['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall']
doy = data.index.dayofyear
data['SEASON1'] = pd.cut(doy + 11 - 366*(doy > 355), bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Answer (score 4):

**[`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)**
*In order to properly handle `'Winter'` being both at the beginning and end of the year, I shifted the `dayofyear` by `11` and took the results modulo `366`.  The reason I don't use the same technique as in the `numpy` solution below is that `pd.cut` returns a categorical type and I would end up with 5 categories in which two categories had the same label.  I could then cast the result as string, but that felt sloppy.*

```
data['SEASON'] = pd.cut(
    (data.index.dayofyear + 11) % 366,
    [0, 91, 183, 275, 366],
    labels=['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall']
)
```

---

**[`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)**
*In order to properly handle `'Winter'` being both at the beginning and end of the year, I allowed two bins for `'Winter'`*

```
seasons = np.array(['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter'])
f = np.searchsorted([80, 172, 264, 355], data.index.dayofyear)
data['SEASON'] = seasons[f]
```

---

**`plot`**

```
data.groupby('SEASON')['impact'].mean().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: i did as you said and i got this error : 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @MarieAntoinette I forget you are on an older version of `pandas`... will update in a second.... Try it now.

Comment: haha oh yeah you still remember , thank you so much  for the edit it's working now

Answer (score 2):

Looks like:

```
data['SEASON'] = data.index.to_series().dt.**month**.map(lambda x : season(x))
```

uses the month presumably 1-12 or 0-11 which are all "winter".
You need to use the day of year.

But you could probably have seen this more easily and made it possible to print to check it yourself if you hadn't locked the extraction of the day away inside a one-liner. Just saying.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, i just print to check and they are all winter, how can i write the day of the year as you said ?