# Is there a datatype of season?

Tags: python, pandas, data-representation

I'm working with AI and have got a data set which is associated with the time of year. With season another word. Temperature, pressure, humidity and so on. Tasks include to determine seasonly close data. I did some research. Details in the attached code. Is there any common datatype to represent the season and, may be the time of day from the astronomical point of view?

I already tried to represent data with trigonometrical function sin and cos.

```
# # The way to represent season.

import pandas as pd
import math

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=365*3, freq='D')

# Time of year is close to what I want, but...
rng[100+2].dayofyear - rng[100].dayofyear
# Out: 2

# ...in some cases it goes wrong:
# Only 2 days range. Almost no difference from the season point of 
# view.
rng[364+2].dayofyear - rng[364].dayofyear
# Out: -363

# Yes, of couse, we still have a chance to fit AI to distinguish what 
#'season' mean. But isn't it to complicate? In fact I want to 
# reproduce some kind of astronomical data.
df = pd.DataFrame(index=rng, columns=('dayofyear','sin','cos'))

# Yes, I no this is not optimal. But this is just for visibility
for day in rng:
    #print (day.dayofyear)
    df.loc[day, 'dayofyear']=day.dayofyear
    df.loc[day, 'sin'] = math.sin(day.dayofyear/365*2*math.pi)
    df.loc[day, 'cos'] = math.cos(day.dayofyear/365*2*math.pi)

# Now, we can see something like season mean:
( df.loc['2012-01-01', 'sin'] - df.loc['2011-12-31', 'sin'] ) * 
( df.loc['2012-01-01', 'cos'] - df.loc['2011-12-31', 'cos'] ) 
# Out: -2.5503444618122675e-06

( df.loc['2012-06-01', 'sin'] - df.loc['2011-12-31', 'sin'] ) * 
( df.loc['2012-06-01', 'cos'] - df.loc['2011-12-31', 'cos'] )
# Out: -0.9111812528724549

# But, may be I just reinvent the bicycle?
# Is there a proper way to reproduce season and "Times of Day"?
```

Comment: Seasons aren’t very universal; many Asian countries recognize a rainy season in addition to the usual four for instance. And the UK experiences four seasons per day. Sooo...

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526662/group-data-by-season-according-to-the-exact-dates) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, season isn't acknowledged in the data type of timestamp, or in the time module.

What you could do is write a forumala to evaluate the date, and determine what season it falls into.