# How to loop through dates column and assign values according to a certain condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df` as follows

```
       dates       winter   summer  rest  Final
2020-01-01 00:15:00 65.5    71.5    73.0   NaN
2020-01-01 00:30:00 62.6    69.0    70.1   NaN
2020-01-01 00:45:00 59.6    66.3    67.1   NaN
2020-01-01 01:00:00 57.0    63.5    64.5   NaN
2020-01-01 01:15:00 54.8    60.9    62.3   NaN
2020-01-01 01:30:00 53.1    58.6    60.6   NaN
2020-01-01 01:45:00 51.7    56.6    59.2   NaN
2020-01-01 02:00:00 50.5    55.1    57.9   NaN
2020-01-01 02:15:00 49.4    54.2    56.7   NaN
2020-01-01 02:30:00 48.5    53.7    55.6   NaN
2020-01-01 02:45:00 47.9    53.4    54.7   NaN
2020-01-01 03:00:00 47.7    53.3    54.2   NaN
2020-01-01 03:15:00 47.9    53.1    54.1   NaN
2020-01-01 03:30:00 48.7    53.2    54.6   NaN
2020-01-01 03:45:00 50.2    54.1    55.8   NaN
2020-01-01 04:00:00 52.3    56.1    57.9   NaN
2020-04-28 12:30:00 225.1   200.0   209.8  NaN
2020-04-28 12:45:00 215.7   193.8   201.9  NaN
2020-04-28 13:00:00 205.6   186.9   193.4  NaN
2020-04-28 13:15:00 195.7   179.9   185.0  NaN
2020-04-28 13:30:00 186.7   173.4   177.4  NaN
2020-04-28 13:45:00 179.2   168.1   170.9  NaN
2020-04-28 14:00:00 173.8   164.4   166.3  NaN
2020-04-28 14:15:00 171.0   163.0   163.9  NaN
2020-04-28 14:30:00 170.7   163.5   163.6  NaN
2020-12-31 21:15:00 88.5    90.2    89.2   NaN
2020-12-31 21:30:00 85.2    88.5    87.2   NaN
2020-12-31 21:45:00 82.1    86.3    85.0   NaN
2020-12-31 22:00:00 79.4    84.1    83.2   NaN
2020-12-31 22:15:00 77.6    82.4    82.1   NaN
2020-12-31 22:30:00 76.4    81.2    81.7   NaN
2020-12-31 22:45:00 75.6    80.3    81.6   NaN
2020-12-31 23:00:00 74.7    79.4    81.3   NaN
2020-12-31 23:15:00 73.7    78.4    80.6   NaN
2020-12-31 23:30:00 72.3    77.2    79.5   NaN
2020-12-31 23:45:00 70.5    75.7    77.9   NaN
2021-01-01 00:00:00 68.2    73.8    75.7   NaN
```

The `dates` column has dates starting from `2020-01-01 00:15:00` till `2021-01-01 00:00:00` split at every 15 mins.

I also have the following date range conditions:

> **Winter:** 01.11 - 20.03
>
> **Summer:** 15.05 - 14.09
>
> **Rest:** 21.03 - 14.05 & 15.09 - 31.10

What I want to do is to create a new column named `season` that checks every date in the `dates` column and assigns winter if the date is in Winter range, summer if it is in Summer range and rest if it is the Rest range.

Then, based on the value in the `season` column, the `Final` column must be filled. If the value in `season` column is 'winter', then the values from `winter` column must be placed, if the value in `season` column is 'summer', then the values from `summer` column must be placed and so on.

How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [group data by season according to the exact dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526662/group-data-by-season-according-to-the-exact-dates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is normalize datetimes for same year, then filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and set new column by [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-2020'))

m1 = d.between('2020-11-01','2020-12-31') | d.between('2020-01-01','2020-03-20')
m2 = d.between('2020-05-15','2020-09-14') 

df['Final'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['Winter','Summer'], default='Rest')
print (df)
                dates  winter  summer  rest   Final
0 2020-01-01 00:15:00    65.5    71.5  73.0  Winter
1 2020-06-15 00:30:00    62.6    69.0  70.1  Summer
2 2020-12-25 00:45:00    59.6    66.3  67.1  Winter
3 2020-10-10 01:00:00    57.0    63.5  64.5    Rest
```